# Установка Rtools

Tags: r, rstudio

Пытаюсь установить Rtools. Скачал его. Далее необходимо выполнить следующую команду в терминале:

```
> writeLines('PATH="${RTOOLS40_HOME}\\usr\\bin;${PATH}"', con = "~/.Renviron")
```

Кто может описать что нужно вставить вместо RTOOLS40_HOME и PATH?

Answer (score 1):

Ничего не надо менять, делайте строго по инструкции https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/, и все получится.

Answer (score 0):

Установите пакет installr. В нем есть функция установки Rtools и многих других нужных программ